# Как в SQL узнать есть ли подстрока или нет?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, sqlite, gdb

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть таблица к примеру,

```
name    cities 
Artem   Rome Paris Moscow
```

Так же я получил значение от пользователя Rome и мне нужно проверить все значения, и вывести Name, там где cities *содержит* подстроку Rome.

Пробовал FIND_IN_SET метод, но не получилось.

Можете подсказать, как это реализовать? Что использовать?

Comment: `cities like '%Rome%'` НО, возникнут очевидные проблемы, если Rome окажется частью другого слова. Единственно верный вариант нормализовать БД, вынести города в отдельную таблицу. Сейчас структура вашей базы нарушает первую нормальную форму https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0 А язык SQL рассчитан на работу с нормализованными данными

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Также можно воспользоваться функцией `instr`:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable as t
WHERE instr(t.cities, "Rome") > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable as t
WHERE t.cities LIKE %Rome%
```